# Hibernate's Delete Method giving StaleStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to delete object using Hibernate's delete method but getting StaleStateException exception.My requirement is to delete an object based on the unique key so for this i am doing something like.

```
String queryString="from Destination destination "+
                                                   "where destination.destinationID = :destinationid";
    tx.begin();
                Query query= session.createQuery(queryString).setParameter("destinationid", destinationId, Hibernate.STRING);
               @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
               List<Destination> list=query.list();
               Destination ds=list.get(0);
                 if(!list.isEmpty())
                  session.evict(ds);
                  session.delete(ds);

                  tx.commit();
```

since i know there will be only one element in the list if its not empty so only fetching the first element from the list (Not sure if this is a good approach)

but when i am running this method i can see the following sql log in my console

```
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection AirTransport.timeTable */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORTTIME 
        where
            TRANSPORTID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection AirTransport.timeTable */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORTTIME 
        where
            TRANSPORTID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection AirTransport.timeTable */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORTTIME 
        where
            TRANSPORTID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection RoadTransport.timeTable */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORTTIME 
        where
            TRANSPORTID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete collection TrainTransport.timeTable */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORTTIME 
        where
            TRANSPORTID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete AirTransport */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORT 
        where
            UUID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete AirTransport */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORT 
        where
            UUID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete AirTransport */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORT 
        where
            UUID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* delete RoadTransport */ delete 
        from
            tr.TRANSPORT 
        where
            UUID=?
```

and than its throwing

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:46)
```

one thing which making me suspicious is that in my Transport table i have three entries only one for AirTransport one for Train and last one for Road and in the TransPortTime table i have three entries one for each Transport type and

i am using TransportTime as composite-element in side all three transport classes

```
<set name="timeTable" table="TRANSPORTTIME" lazy="true">
                        <key column="TRANSPORTID"/>
                        <composite-element
                                class="TransportTime">

                                <property name="deperatureTime" type="java.util.Date">
                                        <column name="DEPERATURETIME" />
                                </property>
                                <property name="arrivalTime" type="java.util.Date">
                                        <column name="ARRIVALTIME" />
                                </property>
                                <other properties>
                        </composite-element>

                </set>
```

i am still unable to figure out whats going wrong so though of asking in the community

---

Just to add some extra information:
i have the below mapping in my destination class for the three respective trabsport classes

```
<set name="airTransport" table="AIRTRANSPORT" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="save-update, delete">
        <key>
            <column name="DESTINATIONID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="AirTransport" />
    </set>
    <set name="roadTransport" table="ROADTRANSPORT" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="save-update, delete">
        <key>
            <column name="DESTINATIONID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="RoadTransport" />
    </set>
    <set name="trainTransport" table="TRAINTRANSPORT" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="save-update, delete">
        <key>
            <column name="DESTINATIONID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="TrainTransport" />
    </set>
```

and in my RoadTransport/Train/Air Transport have following mapping

```
<class name="AirTransport" table="TRANSPORT">
        <id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="UUID" />
            <generator class="uuid"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="destination" class="Destination" fetch="join">
            <column name="DESTINATIONID" />
        </many-to-one>
       <property mappings>
        <set name="timeTable" table="TRANSPORTTIME" lazy="true">
            <key column="TRANSPORTID"/>
            <composite-element
                class="TransportTime">
                <property mappings>
                </composite-element>

        </set>
    </class>
```

Other two mapping files are also identical
so when i removed mapping association of these three classes from parent class my delete functionality started working perfectly.

So this means i am doing fundamenally wrong in mapping the TimeTable class as component inside Transport classes (Air/Train/Road Transport class)

any suggestion in this regard will be much helpfull

Answer (score 3):

StaleStateException is thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating that the Session contained stale data (when using long transactions with versioning). Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that does not exist.

Note that this exception often indicates that the user failed to specify the correct unsaved-value strategy for a class!

http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html

My guess is, your row is updated during this long transaction. And when it tries to commit delete, it sees that the versions are different (the one in your session marked to be deleted and the actual row in db) so a StaleStateException is thrown

Also Query class should have some method called `uniqueResult()` which will return one object result if you are sure it is gonna return one result each and every time you execute it. That will save you some code at trying to get 0th index of List part.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong in (at least) two ways:

- you must check `isEmpty()` before getting the 0th item. Otherwise you risk an exception
- you should not evict before deleting. Get rid of the `evict()` line

Also make sure you don't have database triggers that are tampering with the number of returned rows.

Comment: i was not using evict() but was getting the same exception so while google read some where to use the evict() but it did not helped and yes i am checking for empty list just misplaced the code.

Comment: Since i am using hibernate hbm2ddl.auto property so i am not sure it is creating or associating schema with any kind of trigger

Comment: in that case it is not. but double-check anyway

Comment: i checked no Procedure no triggers at all :(

Comment: Triggers were what caused this problem for me. Thanks for the hint!